# Contiguous memory allocation of std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, stdvector

Consider the allocation of objects pointers for a vector:

```
std::vector<mapSeg*> mapLayer[3];
```

Is it possible to make this implmentation a contiguous array of objects of a fixed size?

Is it possible to allocate a block of memory for 3 * 64 objects and have them addressed in a vector properly like the setup described above? Each of the arrays represents a layer of objects on a 2D map (back, mid, fore), so access to these layers must be consistant

Comment: Technically, it is a contiguous array of objects of a fixed size. But what problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: The Standard requires that the `object*`s in each `vector` be contiguous in memory, and that `array[3]` create the `vector` objects themselves contiguously in memory.  Where the `object*s` point to is another question entirely... it just depends what you place into the `vector` - you are in total control of that.

Comment: I suppose you mean *"a contiguous array of `object`s"*? I.e. you're referring to some type `object`, not to an *object* as a region of storage (as defined in the Standard)?

Answer (score 0):

That depends how much of the semantics you want to preserve. The first step would be

```
std::vector<object> array[3];
```

Now we have a (effectively) a 3 element array of variable size storage.

We could also wrap a `std::vector<object>` maintain three sizes and provide access to a slice of the `vector`. Insertions into one of the subvectors now become rather expensive because possibly a lot of data has to be copied around, something the `std::vector<object> array[3]` version avoids. Iterator invalidation properties would also be stricter.

It depends on what you want to do. If you are going to repeatedly `emplace_back` on either of the three `vector` use the first version, if you fill them in order, don't erase elements, the last version provides marginal benefits.